# python binary version doesnt match rpm version

Tags: python, linux

I have installed manually python (2.7.3). Whoc do I update the rpm version

usr/bin/python -V:

Python 2.7.3

rpm -qf /usr/bin/python:

python-2.6.5-3.el6.x86_64

any suggestions?

linux version: RH6.3

Answer (score 1):

You installed it incorrectly. Instead of `make install` you should run `make altinstall`. This will install the new version of Python parallel to existing versions, and create a new executable in `$PREFIX/bin` with the name of `python` followed by the minor version of Python installed, e.g. `python2.7`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a symlink in `/usr/bin/` called `python2.7`, point to to where you have installed the new Python and use that.

Do not attempt to upgrade or force the default python on a redhat box, because a lot of other tools will stop working.